# Get average of datediff

Tags: sql-server, datetime, average, datediff

We are having trouble with one of our queries. It needs to return the AVG date between order and delivery dates, with the dates taking place in June so we came up with this:

```
Select
       AVG(datediff(day, OrderDate, DeliveryDate)) AS AverageTime
From   Orders, ProductsInOrders
Where  OrderDate BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-30' 
AND    Status = 'Delivered' 
AND    Orders.OrderID = ProductsInOrders.OrderID
```

Yet it only returns NULL values. The order and delivery dates both have a datatype of datetime, which isn't reflected in the query right now but will be later.

Comment: Change the `SELECT AVG...` to `SELECT *` and see any result return

Comment: Yup it returns what we want

Comment: now add `datediff(day, OrderDate, DeliveryDate)` to the result. And verify the result

Comment: Yup we get values back, but some are negative. Is that bad?

Comment: negative mens your `DeliveryDate` is earlier than `OrderDate`

Comment: Looks good to me. Query should return one value. Unless all the `datediff`s evaluate to null, result should be a numeric value. Not sure what the join is for though.